# How to implement an enum and switch statement in Swift based on properties that change?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement

I'm trying to implement some logic in my code to provide a "gate" to segueing to another VC based on an in app purchase.

When the user clicks on the add button I want 3 possible outcomes:

(1) if user has purchased IAP, segue,
(2) if user has not purchased but var x  < 1 (i.e. they haven’t added before), segue so they can add a property once
(3) if user has not purchased but var x >= 1, don’t segue and show alert view

Below is how I think this should be set up in Swift, however I'm not sure how I can get the values I want into my enum? what would work best here in Swift?

```
enum Access {

    case Purchased  //a bool true or false
    case AddOne  // not purchased but people < 1
    case Locked //not purchased and people >= 1

}

switch Access {

    case .Purchased: // segue
    case .AddOne: // segue
    case .Locked: // alertView

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you described an `enum` may not be needed:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
  var purchased = false
  var people = 0

  @IBAction func handleButton (UIButton button) {
    if purchased {
      // segue
    }
    else if people < 1 {
      // segue
    }
    else {
      // alertView
    }
  }
}
```

or, using an `enum` if you've already mapped from (purchased, people) to the enum:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
  var access : Access = .Purchased

  @IBAction func handleButton (UIButton button) {
    switch access {
    case .Purchased:
      // segue
    case .AddOne:
      // segue
    case .Locked:
      // alert
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had wanted to avoid an if statement in favor of the enum/switch approach thinking it would be the more efficient option, but your code demonstrates how simple an if statement would be.  Thanks!!